# Document reference in firestore using react-native(javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Document Reference is used to get document field and its collections from firestore. Following are some examples:

**1. Function to read data from field which is having docRef**
[Firestore schema]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEPK5.png
Here in collection ***people*** there is ***doc*** named ***user1*** which have a field named ***hlpr*** which have docRef for user2 so if i want to access that docRef data i will use following code:

```
function foo4() {
var user1 = db.collection('people').doc('user1') 
user1.get().then((data) => {         //get user1 whole doc using get()
  var t = data.get('hlpr')           //choose field 'hlpr'
  t.get().then((doc) => {            //get 'hlpr' data() from get()
    var user2 = doc.data()           //get whole doc from user2
    console.log(user2.name)          //output field 'name' from user 2
  })
})}
```

**2. Read data from array from of docRef**. In previous image you can see field named 'cts' which is having array of docRef. Code:

```
function foo3() { //function to get data from array of docRef
var user1 = db.collection('people').doc('user1'); //choose user1 doc
user1.get().then((doc) => {                //get data() of user1 using get()
  var contacts = doc.get('cts');                //set var k to field 'cts'
  contacts.forEach((data) => {                  //for each item in array field cts
    var userx = data.get();                 //read data() using get()
    userx.then((doc) => {                   
      var frnd = doc.data();              //set frnd to each data we get from doc
      console.log(frnd.name)              //output their any field value here i have chosen name
    });
  });
})}
```

NOTE: Above code works correctly and you can also use data to put into array also above code might not be best way to get data, but i am a beginner so this is the best i could do.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and what is not working as expected ?

Comment: Is there a better way to perform these operation? because sometimes i get very confused with too many nested code

Comment: You can switch to use `async-await` statements.

Answer (score 1):

You can break your code down to a chain of awaits per the comments but a promise chain if processing one item can be fairly clean.

```js
async function foo4() {
var user2 = await db.collection('people').doc('user1').get()
.then(data => data.get('hlpr'))
.then(doc=> doc.data())
.finally(result => result)
.catch(console.log());
```

you can do some clean code when you nest promise chains.

The second code block has potential errors, if your client exceeds pending 50 documents the client modules will throw errors and fail reads.